# Can I travel with codeine cough syrup past airport security?

Tags: health, airport-security, ireland

I have a chronic bad cough (not COVID-19 though) and I take an over-the-counter codeine based medication. My issue isn't with whether it's allowed as I'm planning on drinking it before I travel to the U.S. I was just wondering whether it will get stopped by airport security.

I'm aware of the 100ml/3.4 oz restriction on liquids however I've heard that there is an exemption made for medicines. Would this be classified as a medicine since it isn't prescribed?

I should mention that I'm travelling from the Republic of Ireland to the U.S. so an international flight.

Comment: Domestic or international flight? And from where to where? Different states/countries may have different rules

Comment: Planning on drinking it? You've asked loads of questions which have a drug dependency theme lying behind them. I remember that one of them was about taking a large quantity of codeine based medicine but I think it's been deleted.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you worried about airport security if there will be none of the medicine left by the time you travel? OTOH you seem to want to take more than 100ml with you.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure if OP is Filipino but 'drink' is used in Filipino English in the context of taking meds.

Comment: If you fly from Ireland to the USA you might well go through passport control and USA style security in Ireland. Not sure if it is going on now but it has in the recent past and you should be ready to see it happen again when you travel.

Comment: Just to be clear, is it your intention to consume all of the syrup between passing security and actually boarding the plane?

Comment: You can take it past security, if it is not more than 100 ml. You do not need a prescription in Ireland, but you do need one in the USA. If US authorities discover what it is and you do not have a prescription, you could face penalties or even refusal of entry. Just be sure to finish it and put it in the bin before arrival. It is perfectly legal for you to use it on your flight, but not on US soil.

Answer (score 5):

### Irish law regarding codeine syrup

According to [the Pharmaceutical Society of Ireland publication for Guidance for Retail Pharmacy Businesses (2017 p 2-6)](https://imj.ie/codeine-usage-in-ireland-a-timely-discussion-on-an-imminent-epidemic/),

> "...in Irish law, codeine is classed as Schedule 5 under the
> Controlled Drug Regulations meaning that it is available to patients
> over the counter in pharmacies under supervision of a pharmacist who
> should make the patient aware of the side effects, especially the
> sedating nature of codeine and emphasise the addictive potential of
> the drug..."

### Airport Security Rules

According to [the security rules of the Dublin Ireland Airport](https://www.dublinairport.com/at-the-airport/security/security-faqs#section-62ec03f4-7e18-41cb-a02f-3d275c6574e0ContentId-62ec03f4-7e18-41cb-a02f-3d275c6574e0), you can bring "over the counter" codeine syrup past security if it is not more than 100 ml and presented in a one litre transparent bag separately at screening. This is intended to allow you to use the medicine during your flight, as needed.

> Q. Can I bring my cough medicine or nose spray in my hand luggage?

> A. Yes, provided these items are in containers not more than 100ml
> and presented in a one litre transparent bag separately at the
> passenger security screening point. If these items are not essential
> for use during your flight we strongly recommend that you pack them
> into your checked in luggage.

Comment: Many flights from Ireland to the US pass through US customs/immigration before departure, so US restrictions also need to be considered if the OP is flying from one of these airports (specifically Dublin/Shannon).